# javascript name regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx for names. Names can optionally start with a title (Dr., Mrs., etc) and otherwise contain two or three names with the middle name optionally abbreviated in the form (X.)

For instance the following names should be matched:

- Dr. Jeff T. Walker
- Susan B. Anthony
- Mr. Michael Binghamton
- Mrs. George Bush

The following should not be matched

- Garfield
- Dr. J
- T. Pain
- The United States of America
- February 15 2020

Here is what I have:

```
^(Dr\.|Mr\.|Mrs\.)?[A-Z][a-z]+\s([A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]\.)\s[A-Z][a-z]+?
```

im not quite sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Comment: [so very relevant](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: what bout digits and symbols? 50 Cent and Ke$ha would be disappointed

Comment: @MikeHometchko, Names are typically not allowed to have [numbers and symbols](http://www.nj.com/news/index.ssf/2008/12/except_for_numerals_or_symbols.html)

Comment: I was being facetious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^((Dr|Mr|Mrs)\. )?[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z]([a-z]+|\.))? [A-Z][a-z]+`

This is what I did to fix it:

- Added a space after the prefix - before, you were matching things like "Dr.James", rather than "Dr. James"
- Removed question mark at the end, after the last name - when not after a parentheses, `?` results in "[lazy matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)" - matching as few characters as possible (in this case, 1)
- made the middle name optional
- Removed some redundancies (such as in the prefix and middle name)
- replaced `\s` with spaces - it's easier to read, and \s matches tabs, newlines, etc.

Comment: aha! you're a miracle worker here... been struggling with this for 30+ min.  thank you for your thorough response & streamlining my existing code!

Comment: You may also want the $ at the end so you can't match something ridiculous like `Dr. Jeff T. Walker !"£$%^&*()0987654321`